# Play framework bind error

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka

I have a play application which I'm actively working on development environment. Somehow it started to give me an error;

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:2552
  while locating play.api.libs.concurrent.ActorSystemProvider
  while locating akka.actor.ActorSystem
    for parameter 6 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:240)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:240)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application
```

I verified that port is not used by any other application but on console I see that

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Play version `2.4.3` and scala version `2.11.7`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer it's simple mistake but I want to document it here to help others like me.

Play application had a dependency to another akka based module. After some changes this jar file was packaged with `application.conf` which is configuring the akka-remote on `2552` port.

Excluding application.conf from dependency solved problem.

Comment: How did you find out, which other dependency had this configuration?
And how did you exclude the application.conf from the other package?

Comment: Hi Fatih, I have same issue.  
How did you find out, which other dependency had this configuration? And how did you exclude the application.conf from the other package?

Comment: @surenyonjan I did debug the play config object. Excluding was easy because it's our own dependency. So we just excluded during build step of that dependency. But if you use some other third party jar which causes configuration issue, you can basically override in your application conf.